# redirect_to not working in Posts controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

For some reason my redirect_to action is no longer working in my Rails 4 app? The error I'm getting is:

```
Missing template posts/create
```

**Posts Controller**

```
  def create
   @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
   if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
   end 
  end

 def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
   @post = Post.new
 end

 def index
   redirect_to root_path
 end

 private

 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:content, :community_id, :user_id, :photo, :photo_file_name)
 end
```

**Routes**

```
 resources :posts do
   member do  
     post :create
   end
 end
```

Comment: Are you sure the `redirect_to` is being reached? What would happen if the post failed to save?

Comment: well even when I add an else to that and allow it to render the 'new' page, in the console it says the same error.

Comment: I get a 302 error in the console actually.

Comment: Firstly, what's up with your routes? ```resources :posts``` already includes a create action.

Secondly, if the ```redirect_to``` isn't working in the current incarnation, redirect to a specific route using the URL helpers, aka ```post_url(@post)```

Comment: I've already tried redirecting to post_url(@posts) and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must not be saving. You can call `@post.valid?` and `@post.errors.full_messages` to see any errors or validation issues. Is there a reason why you are building the new post from the current_user? You could also try `@post = Post.new(post_params)`.

Also you don't need to specify create in your routes. Resource routing has create as a default route. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. I had a validation of storing the user_id, and it was failing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see when running rake routes

```
post POST   /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#create
posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
      POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
      GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
      PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
      PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
      DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

I can see that

```
post POST   /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#create
POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
```

I think this might be the cause of the issues.

I think to make this work you have to remove

```
member do  
 post :create
end
```

from resources :posts

I am not so sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: I removed that and now I get: No route matches [POST] "/posts/new"

Comment: Yes you will get that

Comment: But [Get] "/posts/new" works. To create a new post we will use this one [POST] "/posts"

Answer (score 0):

Here, You need to add `before_action` callback to your controller.

> before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
>
> private
>       def set_post
>         @post = post.find(params[:id])
>       end

Now, You will get value for [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] actions